# how to identify if a css class has property in extjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

i have an element

```
<div class="x-window-header  x-header x-header-draggable x-docked 
 x-unselectable x-window-header-default x-horizontal x-window-header-horizontal 
 x-window-header-default-horizontal x-top x-window-header-top x-window-header-default-top 
 x-box-layout-ct" id="messagebox-1001_header"></div>
```

How to identify which class has a property of `background-color` defined? I tried:

```
var headercls_list = document.getElementById('message-box').firstChild.classList;
      for (i = 0; i < headercls_list.length; i++) 
          {
            if (document.getElementsByClassName(headercls_list[i]).hasOwnProperty('background-color')) 
                {
                    headercls_list[0].style.backgroundColor = '#F00';
                }
          }
```

Even the right class with property background-color returns false! What is wrong here? Im working using DOM. If it can be done with extjs. please suggest

Comment: YOUR html tag is wrong set the child element div starting operator is not there is less then sign

Comment: html tag is right. For some reason when I add div as is, its not appearing on screen. Please ignore syntax error n div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document.getElementsByClassName(headercls_list[i])).css('background-color') !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
```

or without jQuery:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName(headercls_list[i])[0];
var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('background-color');
background !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
```

If it doesn't work for you a more advanced way is to use https://github.com/Box9/jss. Then you can analyze each class in great details:

```
jss.get('.my-class')['background-color']
```

Comment: How to identify if the class has 'background-color' or not.Any function i can use? i would prefer ExtJs

Comment: var el = document.getElementsByClassName(headercls_list[i]);   does not help because I already got the class in one of the headercls_list[i] I want to check. I tried var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(headercls_list[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color'); but does not work. I get error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Sorry it should be `var el = document.getElementsByClassName(headercls_list[i])[0];` You need to pass an element not class name to `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: Did you try `jss` https://github.com/Box9/jss? I think it's more appropriate in your case.

Comment: I dont want to add extra JavaScript library

Comment: @user1463110 it's much work to implement it yourself